# How to combination between digits?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

For given number `N`(Normal number) you must output amount of `N-digit` numbers, such, that last digits of their square is equal to `987654321`.

where `1<=N<=10^6`

It may be simple combinatorics problem. I am not sure. I am trying to find algorithm for this problem. What is the best algorithm to solve this problem?

Comment: It means count the number of n-digit number that satisfies n^2 mod 1000000000 = 987654321, right?

Comment: yes. For clarification follow this link.                                    http://acm.hrbust.edu.cn/vj/index.php?c=problem-problem&id=1028

Answer (score 0):

The question is:

> Find the number of n-digit number x that satisfies `x^2 mod 1000000000 = 987654321`.

**1. Solution for n <= 9**
First, calculate the value of x that satisfies `x^2 = 987654321, 0 <= x < 1000000000`.
You can pre-count in your PC because you only have to check for 10^9 integers.

I calculated the value and the result was following: 
`Result: 111111111,119357639,380642361,388888889,611111111,619357639,880642361,888888889`

Therefore, if `n <= 8` the answer is zero, and if `n = 9` the answer is 8.

**2. Solution for n >= 10**
You can prove this facts because `x^2 mod 1000000000` is cycle with length 10^9.

- There are 8 solutions in `0 <= x < 10^9`.
- There are 8 solutions in `10^9 <= x < 2*10^9`.
- There are 8 solutions in `2*10^9 <= x < 3*10^9`.
- There are 8 solutions in `k*10^9 <= x < (k+1)*10^9 (k is an integer)`.

So, you can say these things.

- There are 8 solutions in `0 <= x < 10^9`.
- There are 80 solutions in `0 <= x < 10^10`.
- There are 800 solutions in `0 <= x < 10^11`.

Therefore,

- There are 72 solutions in all 10-digit number.
- There are 720 solutions in all 11-digit number.
- There are 7200 solutions in all 12-digit number.

So, you only have to output "72" + (n-10 0's) if n > 9.

**3. Conclusion**

- If n <= 8, the answer is 0.
- If n = 9, the answer is 8.
- If n >= 10, the answer is 72 * 10^(n-10).